# Memory overflow VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i'm developing a code, initially[image] i had a trouble with the memory that was filled during the execution of the routine, i could solve partially with "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" but i still having the same trouble but slowly.

Initial solution

Comment: **Your question needs:** 1. A clear, concise statement of the problem you are having, 2.  What behavior you are expecting, 3.  What behavior you are actually getting, 4.  Any error messages you are receiving, 5.  Any data input you are providing, and 6. Code that reproduces the problem in the actual question (not an offsite link).

Comment: Don't use `Integer`. Use `Long`.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code directly into the question - no-one can test your code if you provide it as an image.

Comment: For next time, you will get more responses if you post your code in here as text. Just put 4 spaces before each line and it will post it in a code block. For single parts to be highlighted put a ` on each end

Answer (score 2):

As soon as J gets larger than 32767 it will blow the limit of the Integer, change `Dim J As Integer` to `Dim J As Long` and it will solve your problem